# Remove v-steppers-step icon

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to use vuetify v-stepper but I want to remove the icon in v-stepper-step. How do I remove the icon in v-stepper-step? I have tried adding. I have tried doing a combination of adding edit-icon, append-icon, and even selecting it in style scoped with a property of display: none.

Code that I tried is something like this:

```
<v-stepper-step
 :key="`${stepHeader}-step`"
 :step="index + 1"
 editable
 class="stepper"
 complete
 edit-icon=""
 append-icon=""
>
...
</v-stepper-step>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I put a color="transparent" prop in v-stepper-step

You can still inspect the icon though. For my case, it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your styling:

```css
.v-stepper__step__step {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this. Unfortunately, this does not work

Comment: You can try adding ``!important`` after the display: none. It will work. You need to show us the whole code.